# В чем разница между Git clone и Git pull

Tags: git, github, bitbucket

Я  понимаю что  делают  эти команды,  но не до конца
Каждый  раз  когда  кто-то  делает  коммит,  я должен  пуллить  репозиторий или  клонировать?

Объясните пожалуйста разницу.
Заранее спасибо

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Если чуточку упростить, то можно сказать, что команда `git clone` делает `git init` + `git pull`. `git init` применяться для того, что бы создать пустой репозиторий, а `git pull` - его наполнить с другого репозитория.

Поэтому, если кто то сделал изменения в репозитории, а его у Вас (репозитория) нет, то нужно делать clone. Если репозиторий уже есть у Вас (тут иногда говорят, что он уже был склонирован раньше, но это не совсем верно - ведь он мог быть склонирован на другой машине или был склонирован и удален/разломан в куски), тогда достаточно pull.

Сам pull делает две операции - fetch - это просто утянуть с удаленного репозитария то, чего ещё нет в Вашей копии (для большинства пользователей git на этом моменте как бы ничего не поменялось) и потом merge (по умолчанию) или rebase (зависит от настроек и ключей/предпочтений).

После этого думаю станет понятно, что можно и не делать pull,  а можно просто сделать fetch (если уже есть репозиторий), а потом ручками сделать merge/rebase.

P.S. **режим К.З (капитана занудность)**

*если кто то делать "коммит" в git, то обычно это не значит, что он сделал push и его изменения доступны. И pull/fetch ничего не смогут утянуть.*

**режим К.З выключен**

Answer (score 1):

Git clone - команда клонирования репозитория - используется для первоначального копирования репозитория, т.е. для создания копии на вашей машине, когда у вас вообще ничего нет - скачает всю информацию.

Git pull - команда для получения последних изменений - используется именно для получения последних изменений, т.е. для получения той информации, что добавили ваши коллеги - скачает только последние изменения.